# Alternative to powerpoint shape.Export method

Tags: c#, .net, powerpoint, office-interop

I want to export shapes from ppt to images. I'm using `PowerPoint` api's `shape.Export` method.

like :

```
curShape.Export(path + imageName,JPG_Or_PNG, (int)this.myPPTProcessor.SlideWidth, (int)this.myPPTProcessor.SlideHeight, PpExportMode.ppRelativeToSlide);
```

But I discovered that with Office 2013 they've removed support for `shape.Export()` method and is deprecated. It is risky to rely on this method.

Please suggest me a solution to export shapes as images.

Comment: This option was removed/withdrawn if Office 2010, too. But to be precise, it is not removed but hidden. It's kept for compatibility and I think it's rather low risk if you rely on it. So, go this way...

Comment: Well, I'm using it in a script that runs against 2010 as well, and in fact, it's broken when I try to use it with 2013. See my recent question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17837742/why-am-i-getting-an-illegal-value-error-using-ppshapeformat-in-office-2013-inter?noredirect=1#comment26109490_17837742